# How to disable Auto_Open after first save

Tags: vba, excel

When opening up a template a macro that is `Auto_Open` runs this code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

UserForm.Show

End Sub
```

This then brings up a userform that says `please save as` and a Ok command button.
[image]
When Ok is clicked it has the this code.

```
Private Sub SaveAs_Click()

   Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
   bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
   If Not bFileSaveAs Then MsgBox "User cancelled", vbCritical

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Problem is after the `Auto_Open` is ran for the first SaveAs i want it to never run again. Because I want to be able to open it later with out the Userform popping up. So how do I disable the Auto_Open once its run and then save it disabled

I cant disable all macros because there are others in the workbook that still need to work.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this could as easy as checking to see if the [Workbook.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx) starts with **Book**.

Comment: I just noticed its not saving the file at all, I click ok, Type in the save as window the name "Test this macro" and nothing appears and the template workbook stays open.

Comment: The stock dialog is only going to supply a folder and name. See [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx) for more information. Note that their example only displays the file name; it doesn't actually save the file. More at [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `Workbook.SaveAs` method [MSDN Found Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) after you get the SaveAsFilename...

As for deleting a sub after it runs (I'd do this before saving) [See here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172109)... You'll need your Auto Open Sub in a different module so you can delete the module before saving.

```
Private Sub SaveAs_Click()

Dim x As Object
Set x = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
x.Remove VBComponent:=x.Item("TestModule") 'Where TestModule is the module that holds the Auto Open script

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 

Do 
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename 
Loop Until fName <> False 

NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName

fName = False
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I chose the file I want to save it in. And I didn't get it to work Used: `Private Sub SaveAs_Click()

    Dim FileSaveName As String
    FileSaveName = InputBox.Value
    Workbook("Name of Book").SaveAs FileSaveName
    Unload Me

End Sub             and            Private Sub Inputbox_Change()

    InputBox.Value = " "

End Sub`

Comment: I figured it out, Used `Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    If Not bFileSaveAs Then MsgBox "User cancelled", vbCritical` Still need my second question answered though. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Duraholiday Updated again.

Comment: That link to deleting sub after it runs once ^_^

Comment: @findwindow That is why I said they need to be in separate modules... Since the code would be running in the module you are trying to delete...

Comment: That link is brilliant.

Comment: I get Run-time error '1004' Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not Trusted `Set x = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents`. I have a password on the VBA Project is that why?

Comment: @Duraholiday no, goto trust center, macro settings and you should see a checkbox for "trust access to vba project model". Check that.

Answer (score -1):

Exit auto_open if file name without specific wording.

For example: If file name is not starting from "N", auto_open will be exit.

```
Sub auto_open()

VBA_CODE = ActiveWorkbook.Name
If Left(VBA_CODE, 1) <> "N" Then Exit Sub
```